# Unable to apply "where" clause to a date column in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a date column (in `YYYY-MM-DD` format) in a big query table. I am unable to apply a `where` clause to the date column. I am using the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM [dataSet_Id.TableName] where CR_DT=DATE("2016-01-01")

SELECT * FROM [dataSet_Id.TableName] where CR_DT=DATE("2016-01-01") where CR_DT=20160101
```

So how do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it work, If I use **Standard SQL Dialect** instead of **Legacy SQL**

Sample queries to handle date in where clause:

```
SELECT * from demoschema.demotable where dob = date('2016-08-10');
SELECT * from demoschema.demotable where dob = '2016-08-11';
```

If you want to use **Standard SQL Dialect**, just go to **Show options** then you will find **SQL Version** field which is use for enabling Standard SQL. .Dialect.

Comment: Hey the command you gave works when i query it on the query editor on the BigQuery web page.
But how do i execute it using BQ command as the query fails when I use it on BQ command tool?

Answer (score 2):

If the type of your `CR_DT` column is `String` then:

```
SELECT * FROM [dataSet_Id.TableName] where CR_DT = '2016-01-01'
```

If the type of your `CR_DT` column is `TIMESTAMP` then:

```
SELECT * FROM [dataSet_Id.TableName] where DATE(CR_DT) = DATE(timestamp('2016-01-01'))
```

Comment: Hey my column is of type "Date" not "TimeStamp" nor "String" type. So this is not what i need.

Comment: looks like you got the answer anyway ;-)